# finding area bounded by some curves in a plane region

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Let $R$ be a region in the $xy$-plane bounded by the curves $y=x^2,
>  y=4x^2, xy=1$ and $xy=5$. Then the value of the integral $$\iint_R
>  \frac{y^2}{x}dydx$$ is equal to ________ .

[image]

Now I used the variable limit over $x$ and constant limit over $y$ to get the required area as $$\iint_R
 \frac{y^2}{x}dydx=\int_{y=1}^{\sqrt[3]{4}}\int_{x=1/y}^\sqrt{y}\frac{y^2}{x}dydx+\int_{y=\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{25}}\int_{x=\sqrt{y}/2}^{1/y}\frac{y^2}{x}dydx+\int_{y=\sqrt[3]{25}}^{\sqrt[3]{100}}\int_{x=\sqrt{y}/2}^{5/y}\frac{y^2}{x}dydx$$ But this will involve a log term in the answer and answer is only $12$. Although finding area by this graphical method is too much time consuming, on the other hand. So is there any shortcut method to evaluate this kind of double integral? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We have :$$\iint_R \frac{y^2}{x}dA$$

We can solve this by either doing $$\iint_R \frac{y^2}{x}dydx$$ or $$\iint_R \frac{y^2}{x}dxdy$$
The choice of which to do depends on the simplicity of each of them, for this problem its clear that by taking the first option we avoid logarithms:

so in this case our integral becomes:
$$\int _{x=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{4}}}^1\int _{y=\frac{1}{x}}^{4x^2}\:\frac{y^2}{x}\:dydx+\:\int _{x=1}^{\sqrt[3]{1.25}}\int _{y=x^2}^{4x^2}\:\frac{y^2}{x}\:dydx+\:\int _{x=\sqrt[3]{1.25}}^{\sqrt[3]{5}}\int _{y=x^2}^{\frac{5}{x}}\:\frac{y^2}{x}\:dydx$$
this doesn't yield in any complicated integrals.

Also these are the integrals we would have to solve in case we take the second option, even though its more tedious than the first option both will give the same answer no matter what.
$$\int_{y=1}^{\sqrt[3]{4}}\int_{x=1/y}^\sqrt{y}\frac{y^2}{x}dxdx+\int_{y=\sqrt[3]{4}}^{\sqrt[3]{25}}\int_{x=\sqrt{y}/2}^{\sqrt{y}}\frac{y^2}{x}dxdy+\int_{y=\sqrt[3]{25}}^{\sqrt[3]{100}}\int_{x=\sqrt{y}/2}^{5/y}\frac{y^2}{x}dxdy$$